# How to Execute a SQL query while a Data Reader is opened?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'd like to know how can I execute a SQL query while a data reader is opened?

Code:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" Id Bracelet :{0} | Id Client: {1} | First Name: {2} | Last Name: {3}", reader["IdBracelet"], reader["IdClient"], reader["FirstName"], reader["LastName"]));
        al.Add(reader["IdBracelet"]);
    }

    while (true) 
    {
        Y.Function();
        string strQueryInsert = "Insert into TableZ(xxx, xx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx) values (@xxx, @xx, @xxxx, @xxxxx, @xxxxxx)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQueryInsert, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxx", xxx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xx", xx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxx", xxxx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxxx", xxxxx);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxxxx", xxxxxx);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }                 
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

I need the query to be executed within the reader because I store the values that the reader return in a List and then use those values.

EDIT : When I try to close the reader before starting the while loop, the compiler tells me that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` isn't working.

Is my syntax correct to insert data into my database ?

EDIT2:

The whole code is wrapped in this one :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n List of Bracelets:");

    Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

    connection.Open();
}
```

Do I still need to open a second one though ?

If anybody knows how to fix it , might be very helpful , thanks

Comment: Either: 1) Just open a second connection to the database or 2) Copy the reader into a dataset first, then work from that.

Comment: Do not add a second connection, instead add a 2nd command to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

That is not complete code. while(true)  You are not using al.

This should work.  If not produce more complete code.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" Id Bracelet :{0} | Id Client: {1} | First Name: {2} | Last Name: {3}", reader["IdBracelet"], reader["IdClient"], reader["FirstName"], reader["LastName"]));
        al.Add(reader["IdBracelet"]);
    }
}

string strQueryInsert = "Insert into TableZ(xxx, xx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx) values (@xxx, @xx, @xxxx, @xxxxx, @xxxxxx)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQueryInsert, connection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxx", xxx);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xx", xx);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxx", xxxx);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxxx", xxxxx);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxxxx", xxxxxx);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```